# get detailed informations from glht object

Tags: r

I would like to get p-values and associated factors from a glht object (example code at the end)

`summary(mcptu)$test$pvalues` is ok for p-values, but `rownames(summary(mcptu)$linfct)` is tricky.

With `rownames(summary(mcptu)$linfct)` I get "2 - 1"  "3 - 1"  "4 - 1"  "5 - 1"  "6 - 1"  "3 - 2" that I can split and so on. But there might be an elegant way to get the factors that are compared?

```
library(mratios); library(multcomp)

data(Penicillin)
Penicillin$strain <- as.factor(Penicillin$strain)

linmod <- lm(diameter ~ strain, Penicillin)
mcptu  <- glht(linmod, mcp(strain="Tukey"))
summary(mcptu)
```

thx 
Christof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pairs are just (2, 1), (3, 1), ... (n, 1), then (3, 2), ... (n, 2), ... (n, n).  Create them using `seq` and `rep` variants.

```
get_level_pairs <- function(n)
{
  data.frame(
    x = unlist(lapply(seq_len(n)[-1], seq.int, to = n)),
    y = rep.int(seq_len(n - 1), rev(seq_len(n - 1)))
  )
}

get_level_pairs(nlevels(Penicillin$strain))
```

---

Or split those rownames.

```
library(stringr)
str_split_fixed(rownames(mcptu$linfct), " - ", 2)
```

Comment: thx! for all pair that should work, but when I have a self defined contrast matrix that seems to be trickier.

Comment: that is perfect, thank you very much! unfortunately I am not able to vote currently

Comment: @ChristofKluß if this solves your problem, then click the tick on the left to mark this answer as the solution.